# Excel vba/Macro move row to next column after N row and copy the header

Tags: vba, excel

How to move / cut my row after row 15(n) to next column and repeat my header column  also using command button in excel vba/macro.
i have data like this :
[image]

I want change the row(n) to column using command button and the result like this: 
[image]

Comment: Record a macro while performing the first cut, then use that (modified) in a loop

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Please, show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, rngDB As Range
    Dim vHead
    Dim rngT As Range, i As Long

    Set rngDB = Range("a3").CurrentRegion
    vHead = Range("a3").Resize(1, 2)
    For i = 16 To rngDB.Rows.Count Step 15
        vDB = rngDB.Range("a" & i).Resize(15, 2)
        Set rngT = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
        rngT.Resize(1, 2) = vHead
        rngT.Offset(1, 0).Resize(15, 2) = vDB
    Next i
    rngDB.Offset(16).Clear
    Set rngDB = Range("a3").CurrentRegion
    rngDB.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End Sub
```